# Bind socket in extends react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have a class App in react

```
class App extends Component
```

and in `componentWillMount()` I've initialized the socket `this.socket = io();`.
now if I use the socket in another function outside componentWillMount I recieve an error, for example `anotherfunction(){
    this.socket.emit('welc_message','hello');
}`

I receive

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Comment: I've tried `this.anotherfunction.bind(this);` in componentWillMount. and the same error occurs .

Comment: Can you show more of your code ? probably, since you are doing some async task in 'io()' and as such you need to handle the initialisation of this.socket when IO is finished and thereafter calling setState to re-render

Comment: I've just tried var App = React.createClass instead of extends component and it works so most likely it's a binding issue since extends component doesen't do the automatic binding

Comment: You could also define socket outside of your component completely, then it will be available anywhere in the file, also that way you're not reconnecting everytime the component mounts

Comment: @azium same thing no result. but when I do console.log (this) in the componentWillMount I get the App object which contains socket .
Whereas when I do console.log(this) in anotherfunction I don't get the App function but the local object also console.log(this.socket)  returns undefined

Comment: no I mean.. don't use `this` at all.. just have `var socket = io()` above your component then refer to anywhere as `socket`

Comment: here is my App component
https://codeshare.io/NyYZJ 
I've tried defining socket in the constructor but then in componentWillMount I get Undef

Answer (score 1):

the solution is that in the constructor part we bind the context of anotherfunction so we do that by `this.anotherfunction = this.anotherfunction.bind(this)`
here is how the whole App folder looks like [App.js](https://codeshare.io/PNRAR)